# Vagrantfile setup to allow Ansible to SSH in

Tags: ssh, vagrant, ansible

I have a vagrantfile from a book about Ansible for Devops. The issue I have is that I can SSH into the servers but Ansible cannot. Here is my `vagrantfile`;

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  # General Vagrant VM configuration
  config.vm.box = "geerlingguy/centos7"
  config.ssh.insert_key = false
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |v|
    v.memory = 256
    v.linked_clone = true
 end

# Application server 1
  config.vm.define "app1" do |app|
    app.vm.hostname = "orc-app1.dev"
    app.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.60.4"
 end

# Application server 2
  config.vm.define "app2" do |app|
    app.vm.hostname = "orc-app2.dev"
    app.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.60.5"
 end

# Database server
  config.vm.define "db" do |db|
    db.vm.hostname = "orc-db.dev"
    db.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.60.6"
 end
end
```

And my Ansible `hosts` file;

```
# Application servers
[app]
192.168.60.4
192.168.60.5
# Database servers
[db]
192.168.60.6

# Group 'multi' with all servers
[multi:children]
app
db

# Variables that will be appliedto all servers
[multi:vars]
ansible_ssh_user=vagrant
ansible_ssh_private_key_file=~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
```

I know I can explicitly add `ansible_ssh_port=2200` etc but I'd rather have it setup in the `vagrantfile`

Comment: See https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/ssh_settings.html  . `config.ssh.port`, `config.ssh.host` and more.

Comment: I did see them, but I'm unsure of the parameters

Comment: Here is an example https://gist.github.com/franciscotfmc/9517513d0e185eca5b2247f17d913004

Comment: Please note that you are using a key in ansible, and in vagrant you have config.ssh.insert_key=false

Answer (score 1):

You are using an ssh key to authenticate ansible, and as such you configure in vagrant a user with an ssh key, as in:

```
config.ssh.insert_key = true
config.ssh.username = "deploy-user"
config.ssh.private_key_path = "shared/deploy-user.pem"
```

I also advise the ssh user not to be root, but a user with sudo capabilities when in a production setting.

The other alternative is to put the ansible user rsa private/public key by hand in a newly provisioned system. The place is ~ansible_user/.ssh/authorized_keys

Comment: I have something like that in the etc/ansible/hosts file

Comment: @eekfonky Of course you have, but that is on ansible side. The system being provisioned has to have the SSH ansible public key there for ansible to be able to login.